# Getting error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method putExtra(String, String) from the type Intent"

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to get the data from an EditText in my first screen and then be able to use this in my second screen. I am using putExtra method but it keeps giving me the error message

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method putExtra(String, String) from the type Intent

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!!!

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            buttonSound.start();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));
            Intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString());
        }});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of `Intent` first:

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            buttonSound.start();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? You need to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create instance of Intent class then to use

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);
        @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
           buttonSound.start();
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class) ;          
           intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString());
           startActivity(intent);
        }});
```

Comment: I wrote "Intent" instead of "intent" as my object, and this caused failure. "intent" (of the Intent class) worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.word);

Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn2);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        buttonSound.start();
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class)
        startActivity(intent);
       intent..putExtra("name", et.getText().toString());
        //Intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString());//**This cause problem in your code**
    }});
```